# Show that $K_{1,t}{^{(m)}}(s) = \frac{(t-s)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!}.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know by definition that
$$K_1(s,t) = \int_0^1 \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!} \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!} \,dx.$$

want to show that if we fix $t$, that
$$K_{1,t}{^{(m)}}(s) = \frac{(t-s)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!}.$$
I'm having trouble showing this. My attempt was to write $G_m(t,x) = \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!}$, so that
$$K_1(s,t) = \int_0^1 G_m(t,x) \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}_+}{(m-1)!} \,dx.$$
Then
$$\frac{d^m}{ds^m}K_1(s,t) = \frac{d^m}{ds^m} \int_0^s G_m(t,x) \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \,dx. $$
But from here I don't see how to proceed. Is it because of the derivative of an improper integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you want to prove is composed of the following two cases:

1. $s< t$: we have to show that $$\frac{d^m}{ds^m}\int_0^s \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,dx=\frac{(t-s)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,.$$
2. $s> t$: we have to show that $$\frac{d^m}{ds^m}\int_0^t \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,dx=0=\frac{(t-s)_+^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,.$$

In the second case the function to be differentiate (in $s$) is a polynomial of degree $m-1$ meaning the $m$-th derivative in $s$ vanishes.
The first case is more interesting --- here you'll need the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $-\infty\leq a<b\leq\infty$ and set $I:=(a,b)$. Then, given $f:I\times I\to\mathbb R$ differentiable as well as $s_0\in I$ the map
> \begin{align*}
> g:I&\to\mathbb R\\
> s&\mapsto \int_{s_0}^s f(s,x)\,dx
> \end{align*}
> is differentiable with derivative
> $$
> g'(s)=f(s,s)+\int_{s_0}^s \frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\,dx\tag{1}
> $$
> for all $s\in I$.

*Proof.* Given $s\in I$, by definition
\begin{align*}
g'(s)&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_{s_0}^{s+h} f(s+h,x)\,dx-\int_{s_0}^s f(s,x)\,dx}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\Big(\frac{\int_{s_0}^{s+h} f(s+h,x)\,dx-\int_{s_0}^{s+h}f(s,x)\,dx}h+\frac{\int_{s_0}^{s+h}f(s,x)\,dx-\int_{s_0}^s f(s,x)\,dx}h\Big)\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\Big(\int_{s_0}^{s+h} \frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\,dx+\frac1h\Big(\int_{s}^{s+h}f(s,x)\,dx\Big)\Big)\,.
\end{align*}
Now the following two steps are what gets us from this expression to (1), thus concluding the proof:

- $\frac1h(\int_{s}^{s+h}f(s,x)\,dx)\to f(s,s)$ as $h\to 0$:

This is just the [fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) applied to the function $x\mapsto f(s,x)$.

- $\int_{s_0}^{s+h} \frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\,dx\to \int_{s_0}^s \frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\,dx$ as $h\to 0$:

We compute
\begin{align*}
\Big|&\int_{s_0}^{s+h} \frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\,dx-\int_{s_0}^s \frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\Big|\,dx=\\
&=
\Big|\int_{s_0}^{s} \frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\,dx+\int_{s}^{s+h} \frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\,dx-\int_{s_0}^s \frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\,dx\Big|\\
&\leq
\int_{s_0}^{s} \Big|\frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h-\frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\Big|\,dx+\int_{s}^{s+h} \Big|\frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\Big|\,dx\,.
\end{align*}
Because $\frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h-\frac{d}{ds}f(s,x)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ by assumption the associated (definite) integral converges to zero, as well.
Assuming $h$ "sufficiently small" (i.e. $s+h\in I$) the second summand can be upper bounded by
\begin{align*}
\int_{s}^{s+h} \Big|\frac{f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)}h\Big|\,dx&\leq \big( \max_{x\in[s,s+h]}|f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)|\big)\Big(\underbrace{\int_{s}^{s+h}\frac1h \,dx}_{=1}\Big)\\
&=\max_{x\in[s,s+h]}|f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)|\\
&\leq\max_{x\in I}|f(s+h,x)-f(s,x)|\,.
\end{align*}
But $f$ is differentiable (hence continuous) meaning $f(s+h,x)\to f(s,x)$ as $h\to 0$ for **all** $x\in I$ so taking the maximum over all $x$ still yields zero.$\quad\square$

As one readily verifies this lets us compute
\begin{align*}\frac{d^m}{ds^m}\int_0^s \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \frac{(s-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,dx&=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} \underbrace{\frac{d^{m-1}}{ds^{m-1}}\frac{(s-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}}_{=1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^s \frac{(t-x)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}\,dx=\frac{(t-s)^{m-1}}{(m-1)!}
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!